# Clicking link changes url in browser bar, but doesn't actually load URL (may be AnythingSlider related)

Tags: hyperlink, href, anythingslider

I'm using AnythingSlider. I have a link to a certain page and slide, like this:

```
<a href='http://sitename.com/pagename/#panel1-1'>Click Me</a>
```

Updated for clarity: the problem was that when I create a link like this, the direct link to the page & slide works when the link isn't on the page with the slide, but it doesn't work when it's on the same page as the slide. Since I have these links all over my site, and it's dynamic, I needed a way to be able to simply link to a slide, that would work on any page - including the page where the slide is.

I found a solution - I'm linking to the slide just as I was before, and then dynamically updating the action on that link for pages where the link appears on the same page as the slider.

** My solution (the gist I used to my site, edit to suit your purposes): **

```
//Get anythingslider links, and dynamically update them so that they jump to the slider
    $("a").each(function(){

        var pathname = window.location.pathname.replace(/^https?:\/\/critter.co/,'');

        var link = this.href.replace(/^https?:\/\/critter.co/,'');

        if(link.indexOf("/settings/home") == 0 && pathname.indexOf("/settings/home") == 0){
            $(this).removeAttr("href");
            slidenum = parseInt(link.charAt(link.length-1));
            $(this).click(function(){
                $("ul#slider").anythingSlider(link.charAt(link.length-1));
            });
        }

        if(link.indexOf("/record/home") == 0 && pathname.indexOf("/record/home") == 0){
            $(this).removeAttr("href");
            slidenum = parseInt(link.charAt(link.length-1));
            $(this).click(function(){
                $("ul#slider").anythingSlider(link.charAt(link.length-1));
            });
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand you, with pages being on the right side. But I think the issue you're having is the link itself is only changing the URL and not the slides, right?

First off, the `pagename/` is linking to another page, so that should be working. If you want to control the slider from the same page, you'll only need the `#1-1` part; well, if you have multiple sliders on the page.

### One Slider ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/4085/))

- If you only have one slider, you can do something like this:

  ```
  <nav>
      Go to slide:
      <a href="#1">One</a> | <a href="#2">Two</a> | <a href="#3">Three</a> |
      <a href="#4">Four</a> | <a href="#5">Five</a>
  </nav>
  ```

  and this code to go make the slider go to that particular slide:

  ```
  $('nav a').click(function(){
      $('#slider').anythingSlider( $(this).attr('href').substring(1) );
  });
  ```

### Multiple Sliders ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/4086/))

- In this HTML, I've added an index for the slider in the href attribute - `#1-1` means slider 1, panel 1. So here is an example of a nav for multiple sliders (more can be added as desired):

  ```
  <nav>
      top slider: <a href="#1-1">One</a> | <a href="#1-2">Two</a> | <a href="#1-3">Three</a> |
      <a href="#1-4">Four</a> | <a href="#1-5">Five</a>
      <br>
      bottom slider: <a href="#2-1">One</a> | <a href="#2-2">Two</a> | <a href="#2-3">Three</a> |
      <a href="#2-4">Four</a> | <a href="#2-5">Five</a>
  </nav>
  ```

  Then this code can be used to control the sliders:

  ```
  $('nav a').click(function(){
      var link = $(this).attr('href').match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/),
          slider = parseInt( link[1], 10 ) - 1; // eq needs zero based index
      $('.slider').eq( slider ).anythingSlider( link[2] );
  });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) It didn't answer my question - I wasn't clear enough - but I found the answer, updating my question for clarity and the solution. Thanks again. :)